# How can I get the cells in a UICollectionView Controller to have text, which each cell's text drawn from a 2D array?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a table I'm trying to create in which there are as many cells as inner elements in a 2D array, and I want each cell to have text on it. For example, if I have an array:

```
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

the first cell should have 1, the next one 2, the last one 6.

I had tried putting a Label into the sample cell in the collection view, but when I try to connect it to the CollectionViewController as an IBoutlet, I get an error. How can I get this done?

Comment: You have to create a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` - head over to google and do a quick search for `swift custom UICollectionViewCell` and you will find many, many examples and tutorials.

Comment: would you mind giving me a sample of how I can do this with as little programmatical as possible? It took me a long time to get the cells there in the first place

Comment: Paste the error message.